# Emoji unicode values

Tags: android, unicode, android-softkeyboard, emoji, ime

I'm building my own Android IME and I don't know what should I put in `android:keyCodes=""` or `android:keyOutputText=""` in `Keyboard.Key` in order to type EMOJI? When I try "U+1F601", "\u1F601" and stuff like that my keyboard isn't showig at all or it just types empty character. I've have implemented this keyboard https://github.com/zeuxisoo/android-emoji-keyboard and it has integer in `android:keyCodes` and it shows emoji when I'm typing in Facebook Messenger, but when I type in EditText in any other app it shows a Chinese character and on some devices empty box. Please help. Thanks in advance.